# jQuery to Set JS Variable in MVC App

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, onclick

I'm transferring some very simple File Copy C# code into an MVC App. I have the server side code correct, but am having difficulty with some JS/jQuery/HTML code.

I am attempting to set the JS variable 'test' to the Source and Environment HTML input boxes once the button is clicked.

I believe my function setTest &/or my jQuery are not working correctly. I am either calling it incorrectly from the HTML, or I have a few things out of order in the JS. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
HTML:

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="usr">source:</label>
     <input type="text" id="source" class="form-control">

     <label for="pwd">environment:</label>
     <input type="text" id="env" class="form-control">

     <button type="button" id="source" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="setTest(); myApp.getCSharp()">GetC#</button>
</div>

JavaScript

var test = {

    "source": "",
    "Environment": ""
}

function setTest() {

    test.source = $('#source').toString; //can be .val too
    test.Environment = $("#env").toString();

}


    if (test.source == "<hard coded value>" && test.Environment == "<hard coded value>") {

        var myApp = {

            getCSharp: function () {

                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:50670/api/values/1",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var x = data;
                        $("#myDiv").html(x);

                    //},
                    error: function () {

                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: change dataType: "json" to dataType: "html",

Comment: Still didn't seem to work. The text box input is matching my hard coded values in the if statement, but the getCSharp function is still not being called, so I'm assuming test is not being set. Thank you for the response

Comment: Why are you writing the $.ajax function inside myApp ? write the $.ajax function directly inside if() block, remove your var myApp = { getCSharp: function (){} }

Comment: if you need myApp variable, then add this line - myApp.getCSharp(); after var myApp = { //code };

Answer (score 0):

you need to call getCSharp function. try this:

```
if (test.source == "<hard coded value>" && test.Environment == "<hard coded value>") {

    var myApp = {

        getCSharp: function () {

            $.ajax({
                dataType: "html",
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:50670/api/values/1",
                success: function (data) {
                    var x = data;
                    $("#myDiv").html(x);
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
          } //end getCSharp func
        } //end myApp
   myApp.getCSharp(); //call getCSharp func
   } //end if
```